# Can an image have a full 3D effect without using special glasses?

Tags: 3d

Can we put 3D effect in an image and watch this without using any coloured glasses ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are really asking two completely different questions.

1. Can we put 3D effect in an image?
2. Can I watch a 3D image without using any coloured glasses?

For #1, consider that 3D images are not a single image, the 3D effect is achieved by having two different images taken from a slightly different point of view. To see the 3D effect you have to feed these two images one to each eye. This approximates how we see the real world.

So really, if you have a single image you cannot see 3D. Though you can use post-production techniques to generate two images from your single image. This is how some 2D movies are "converted" to 3D.

There is good information about 3D imagery in the [Stereoscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy) page on Wikipedia.

Regarding #2, there are a few ways to see 3D images without glasses. But most require either glasses (to filter the two images being displayed and provide a single image to each eye) or specialized display hardware (to split the two images based on the angle of view each eye is at with respect to the display).

There is one interesting method that doesn't require any special hardware nor glasses and that is quite easy to achieve. It's commonly called "Wiggle 3D". [This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22951/how-are-these-3d-images-made) has a pretty good example of this technique, and my answer there points to a tutorial on how to make them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [holography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography) would be one example. Here's on explanation of "[How Holograms Work](http://science.howstuffworks.com/hologram.htm/printable)".

Also, on a smartphone, it would be possible to use a combination of [anamorphosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphosis) and the phone's [gyroscopic sensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope#Modern_uses) to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try wiggle stereoscopy or wiggle 3D. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiggle_stereoscopy) for the explanations.

In short: Take two pictures with a normal 2D camera. Just shift the camera between the pictures. Then load the two images in an image editing software in two separated layers, adjust the position and rotation, crop them and export them.

The first difficulty is to adjust both images as very slight shifting or rotating will spoil the 3D effect.

The second difficulty is to produce a convenient output. Animated GIF produces big files, specially if you are using a transition effect between the both images. But, you can also use two images or one side by side and use Java Script or CSS to display and hide one image on a web page (see example link below).

The third difficulty is the time spent per image. Only a few percentage of the images is suitable for wiggling. And you will see the results only when all the work is done.

There is software around easing this process. I am related to one of the company so I can't put any link here.

But I put some examples of adjusted wiggle 3D images, displayed out of two JPEG images wiggling with CSS, on my private web site http://www.tomic.ch/wiggletest/

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answers. It's actually okay to link to your company when it's relevant -- you just need to mention that connection, and also (as you have) give answers that are helpful in themselves. (Also, you can put whatever links you want in your personal profile page.) And welcome to Stack Exchange!